# how to display results on label with sql

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

**UPDATE**
i changed sql query (just test it and it works on sql but still not working with java dont no why :(

Hi how to add get result on `jLabel` with this code? and is it possible to show results on `jTable`?

```
private void searchTeacherActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    String sql = ("select student_ID, firstName, afterName FROM student JOIN studentHom ON course = studentHom_ID WHERE prefect = ?

    try {
        pst = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

        pst.setString(1, larareSoka.getText());
        pst.execute();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, e);
    }
}
```

Comment: `is it possible to show results on jTable?` - yes. There are plenty of examples in the forum. Search the forum using keywords like "JTable" and "ResultSet".

Comment: (1-) `still not working with java` -  Why can't you still ask a proper question??? We can't guess what is not working?

Answer (score 1):

**First** don't use `(?)` you can just use `?`:

```
select ... where course.courseStart = ? and course.corse.end = ?
```

**Second** you have to set parametters to your query in your case you have tow, so you have to use :

```
pst.setString(1, value_of_courseStart);
pst.setString(2, value_of_corse.end);
```

**Third** to get results you have to use ResultSet like this :

```
ResultSet result = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
if (result.next()) {
    String firstname = result.getString(1);
    //----------------------------------^
    //...same for the other columns
}
```

or you can use the name of column like this:

```
ResultSet result = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
if (result.next()) {
    String firstname = result.getString("firstName");
    //--------------------------------------^^
    //...same for the other columns
}
```

**Note**

1. If you want to get multiple result you ca use `while` instead of `if`.
2. Your query is a little wired why you are using :

> ```
> course.courseStart = (?) and course.corse.end = (?)
> //no point---^                           ^------Why this point here
> ```

Did you mean `course.courseStart = ? and course.corseEnd = ?`

Comment: not working :( but in your code is it suppose to refer to the jLabel thu?

Comment: java.lang illegalargumentexception :(

Comment: yes because you miss to set the parameters to your query check the second point @Inger

Answer (score 0):

```
ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery(); 
String firstname = rs.getString("firstname");
..
jLable.setText(firstname);
```

...You need to read the data from the resultset

Comment: Select your code and then use the `{}` button to keep the formatting of the code you pasted.

Comment: still not showing anything just error java.lang.illegalargumentexception

Comment: Look at YCF_L solution...that looks more complete...you need to check the ResultSet to see if there any data with "if (rs.next())..."

Comment: can you post the source code? When you say its not working...do you know if there are any data return?

Comment: @Inger, `i tryed everything but still not working`  - "not working" is not a description of the problem. What is "not working". Does the SQL work. Do you have data in the ResultSet. Did you use System.out.println() to display the value of the first name. Do some basic debugging on your own BEFORE you post questions. Not only that you still haven't searched the forum for examples.

Comment: ok,  i just changed the sql and i test it its working, but i don't understand  data in the resultSet thu? please explain :)

Comment: hi again just wondering does resultSet works with a separate database connection class?  and do i need to add some sort of resultSet code in that class? thanx

Comment: Please read the JavaDoc on ResultSet as it can explain much better than I :). Just think of it as an Object which holds the selected rows. Then you have helper methods which navigates and fetch the values.